# Error source file is not valid UTF-8 when sharing project code from Ubuntu host to macOS guest

Tags: macos, mount, mount-point, mounted-volumes, shared-file

I have a Ubuntu host and a vmware macOS guest. When I share a project code from Ubuntu, the code cannot be built in macOS because of error `source file is not valid UTF-8`. We can use any example of Qt/QML to reproduce this error. I think this is because of "end of line", "end of file" differents. Can you tell me if there are any option/flag in qmake that tell qmake or clang knows about this? Thanks!

**Addition info**: I found the reason but not found the solution. This is because of vmware shared folders in macosx guest is under `/Volumes/VMware Shared Folders`. I must copy the source to another path to build success. I tried to create a symlink but this cannot be built too. I don't want to copy/paste code each time I pull/commit. It's so inconvenient. Can you give me some hints? Thank you very much!
**Addition info**: I cannot read/write those vmware shared folder directly.
Some more info: https://communities.vmware.com/thread/175917.
**Addition info**: Now I can read/write by change both setting in host and guest for the sharing folder. But the issue is still here. I think this is because of the space in the name `/Volumes/VMware Shared Folders`. How can I change this default shared name or mount this to my folder?
**Additon info**: Tried this but still failed: `sudo mount -t vmhgfs ".host:/VMware Shared Folders" /Users/username/sharefolder`

Comment: I've tried moving source codes from shared folder to home directory and yet got the same until I cleared "executable" flag from cpp/hpp files.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem today.
Finally I give up sharing folder over VMware, and turn to sshfs, which is hosted by WSL in the host windows system， everything works.

btw, install sshfs on OSX：

```
brew cask install osxfuse
brew install sshfs
sudo chown ${whoami}  /usr/local/share/man/man1 
brew link sshfs
```